# My flash is recognised as a hard disk drive. How can I fix it?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I have a removable flash disk drive (Sandisk Cruzer blend 32 GB). I have accidently changed it to active partition!

Now it is runing as a local hard disk disk instead of flash disk. How can I make run as default flash disk?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one partition active at a time. So to remove the active partition from the flask disk just set the original disk to active. This should be the one marked C: in your case.